# How to turn off transparency in Matplotlib's 3D Scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib's Axes3D to create a scatter plot with custom colors like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(xval, yval, zval, c=cval, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

This works fine, but matplotlib automatically adds some shading to make more distant points appear more transparent/in a lighter color than closer points. This makes it very hard to visually compare the colors of the individual points.

Is there some way to turn this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `depthshade=False` as an argument in the scatter function.

```
ax.scatter(xval, yval, zval, c=cval, cmap=plt.cm.gray, depthshade=False)
```

[Matplotlib 3D tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `alpha = 1` as argument in the scatter function.

`ax.scatter(xval, yval, zval, c=cval, alpha = 1, cmap=plt.cm.gray)`