# Cube in python - setting of the color of scatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d

How to prevent the scatters from changing the colour in dependence on the angle of view, please?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from itertools import product, combinations

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,6])
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.azim = -112   # y rotation (default=270)
ax.elev = 31     # x rotation (default=0)

ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), np.diag([0.2, 1, 1, 1]))

r = [-1, 1]
for s, e in combinations(np.array(list(product(r, r, r))), 2):
    if np.sum(np.abs(s-e)) == r[1]-r[0]:
        ax.plot3D(*zip(s, e), color='black', lw=1.5)

x_w = [0.5, 0.3]
y_w = [0, 0.6]
z_w = [0, -0.6]
ax.scatter(x_w, y_w, z_w, marker = 'o', s=500, facecolors=(0, 0, 0, 0), edgecolors = 'black')

ax._axis3don = False
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to avoid this is to plot each point individually via

```
for i in range(len(x_w)):
    ax.scatter(x_w[i], y_w[i], z_w[i], marker = 'o', s=500, facecolors=(0, 0, 0, 0), edgecolors = 'black' )
```

If this is not an option for you, you may want to have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533246/controlling-alpha-value-on-3d-scatter-plot-using-python-and-matplotlib) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674885/how-to-turn-off-transparency-in-matplotlibs-3d-scatter-plot) thread. The argument `depthshade = False` may be the solution you are looking for. Unfortunately, I was unable to get the code to run with `depthshade` turned off. It is not working for instances with more than one point in my matplotlib installation, but [this link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18156) might point you to a solution.