# Getting viridis colorbar for all cmaps in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize the features obtained from TSNE. I have two questions:

1. Why am I getting viridis in color bar even though I have specified another cmap?
2. I want to use the cmap colors to plot the features for all images in a 3d plot. I want to use a single color for all 256 coordinates of a single image. Is the below code correctly doing so?

Below is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma', 1000)
i = 0

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

features = np.random.rand(1000, 256, 2)

for fvec in features:
    if(i%50 == 0):
      x_coord, y_coord = fvec.T
      p = ax.scatter(i, x_coord, y_coord, color=cmap(i))    
    i = i+1
    
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

[This is the output that I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tww3R.png)

**EDIT**: First question is solved with help from comments.
Clarification on second question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

features = np.random.rand(1, 100, 2)

i = 0
for fvec in features:
    x_coord, y_coord = fvec.T
    p = ax.scatter(i, x_coord, y_coord, c=i*np.ones(len(x_coord)), norm=plt.Normalize(0,1), cmap='plasma')
    i = i+1
    
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

In this, among the 100 points plotted, some are of a darker color and some lighter. Are all points not using the same color?

[See the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruczl.png)

Comment: @JohanC getting an error in what you suggested but I see the problem now. Shouldn't `p = ax.scatter(i, x_coord, y_coord, color=cmap(i), cmap='plasma')` fix it? It still shows the viridis colorbar.

I want to ensure that the coordinates `x_coord` and `y_coord` for a given `i` use a single color from the color map.

Comment: As per the matplotlib documentation of scatter, cmap argument will get ignored if c is RGBA, which is the case here. Could you please help with the method to specify the color so that a single color is used for all 256 points (for a given value of `i`)? Thanks!

Comment: Ups, there was an `a` missing in `ax.scatter(i, x_coord, y_coord, c=i, norm=plt.Normalize(0,1000), cmap='plasma')`.  The norm makes sure that `c=i` gets the color corresponding to `i` supposing a range from 0 to 1000.  (I still don't quite understand your second question ...)

Comment: Yes, I had tried it but it is raising the error - `TypeError: len() of unsized object`

Comment: Yes. The version is 3.6.2. I am getting the error - `ValueError: 'c' argument has 1 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 256.` with your suggested approaches. 
I tried putting the normalized RGBA values that I am getting from cmap in a 2D array but still getting `UserWarning: No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'cmap' will be ignored`. I used this - 
`ax.scatter(i, x_coord, y_coord, c=np.array([cmap(i)]), cmap='plasma')`
Here `cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma', 1000)` (see the code snippet in my question)

Comment: In that case, `ax.scatter(i, x_coord, y_coord, c=i*np.ones(len(x_coord)), norm=plt.Normalize(0,1000), cmap='plasma')` maybe?

Comment: Yes, solved now! Thanks a lot!
P.S. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: When I plot only one set of 256 points (that is, using `if(i%1000 == 0)` in the code snippet in question), some points have a darker blue and others have a lighter shade. Are all points (`x_coord, y_coord`) not using the same color?

Comment: You probably want to change the `vmax` in `plt.Normalize(0,1000` from `1000` to your maximal value for `i`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Could you please see the edit in the question? I have attached the code and output which shows the different colors.

Comment: It seems matplotlib automatically also changes color depending on the depth. See [How to turn off transparency in 3D Scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674885/how-to-turn-off-transparency-in-matplotlibs-3d-scatter-plot), where `depthshade=False` is suggested.